# F5 bigip network access application failed to run on Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS based) distro

Tags: f5-big-ip, linuxmint, ubuntu-18.04

We are using F5 VPN, and I found a bug and work around:
F5 network access client failed to run with error:

```
 ~ $ /opt/f5/vpn/f5vpn %u
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_init_ssl
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_init_crypto
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ASN1_STRING_get0_data
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve RSA_bits
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_new_null
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_push
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_num
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_pop_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_value
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve DH_get0_pqg
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_options
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_client_random
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_SESSION_get_master_key
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_session_reused
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLS_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLS_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLS_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_getm_notBefore
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_getm_notAfter
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_get_version
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OpenSSL_version_num
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OpenSSL_version
qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
Gtk-Message: 13:18:49.885: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
```

and .F5Networks/vpn.log says:

```
2018-08-14,13:18:49:849, 4212,4212,, 0,,,,  =====================================
2018-08-14,13:18:49:849, 4212,4212,, 0,,,,  Location: /opt/f5/vpn/f5vpn
2018-08-14,13:18:49:849, 4212,4212,, 0,,,,  Version: 7160.2018.0118.1
2018-08-14,13:18:49:849, 4212,4212,, 0,,,,  Locale: C
2018-08-14,13:18:49:849, 4212,4212,, 0,,,,  Qt version: 5.9.5
2018-08-14,13:18:49:849, 4212,4212,, 0,,,,  =====================================
2018-08-14,13:18:49:849, 4212,4212,, 0,,,,  
2018-08-14,13:18:49:849, 4212,4212,, 48,,,, current log level = 63
2018-08-14,13:18:49:850, 4212,4212,, 48, /Helpers.h, 117, void f5::qt::setupLogs(const string&, const string&), QT - OpenSSL supported: false. Lib in use: . Build: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
2018-08-14,13:18:49:850, 4212,4212,, 48, /Helpers.h, 118, void f5::qt::setupLogs(const string&, const string&), F5 - OpenSSL build version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
2018-08-14,13:18:49:918, 4212,4212,, 2, /CustomQApplication.h, 216, void f5::qt::CustomQApplication::loadTranslationFile(const QString&), Translator error: locale:'ru_RU', file 'qt_', from: ':/'... failed to load/failed to install
2018-08-14,13:18:49:921, 4212,4212,, 1, /SessionManager.cpp, 198, bool f5::qt::SessionManager::CreateAndLaunchSessionInternal(const QUrl&), Unsupported external protocol handler request %25u
2018-08-14,13:18:49:921, 4212,4212,, 48, /SessionManager.cpp, 238, void f5::qt::SessionManager::CheckSessions(), No live sessions, quitting application....
```

Last error -

> Gtk-Message: 13:18:49.885: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

fixed by running

> ~ $ qt5ct

and selecting "Windows" style. 
The main problem fixed by creating links to new openssl libraries in vpn client directory -

```
$ ls -al /opt/f5/vpn/lib
итого 8
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  66 авг 14 12:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 200 авг 14 13:25 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  42 авг 14 12:59 libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 авг 14 12:59 libssl.so.1.0.0 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
```

Comment: Not so much a question as a  tutorial

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in QT and openssl - 
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68156

The workaround for last error -

> Gtk-Message: 13:18:49.885: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

fixed by running

> ~ $ qt5ct

and selecting "Windows" style.

And the main problem fixed by creating links to new openssl libraries in vpn client directory -

```
$ ls -al /opt/f5/vpn/lib
итого 8
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  66 авг 14 12:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 200 авг 14 13:25 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  42 авг 14 12:59 libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 авг 14 12:59 libssl.so.1.0.0 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
```